# Too many callbacks.. nodeJS airtable api

Tags: node.js, callback, promise, airtable

First of all I am a newbie in NodeJS and want to imporve my skills on it. 
I have a table in Airtable and want to get all the elements from it. 
Easy with the airtable api for nodejs. 
But what I want to do is push and save these elements in a tab for the future(JSON, excel ...).
To do so, I am using callbaks since the call is async.. I heared about Promises but it's very new to me, and I am hardly uderstanding it..
Here is my code for now:

```
var Airtable = require('airtable'); 
Airtable.configure({
    endpointUrl: 'https://api.airtable.com',
    apiKey: 'keyKWYJPOEObWhNt2'
});
var base = Airtable.base('app4qIwfmG0ZKAdBH');
var view = "Main View";


var tab = [];
base('Table 1').select({
    view : view}).eachPage(function page(records, fetchNextPage){records.forEach(function(record){
        tab.push({
            "Name": record.get('Name'), 
            "Notes": record.get('Notes')
        });
    });
    fetchNextPage();
    pushToArray(tab);
}, function done (error){
    if(error){ console.log(error);
        console.log(tab);}
});

function pushToArray(tab) {
    TabToJson(tab);
    return tab;
};

function TabToJson(tab){
    console.log(tab);
    return JSON.stringify(tab); 
};
```

How can I implements promises? Is it necessary here? I don't want to end up with dozen of callback functions..
Thank you all and have a nice day!

Comment: This will be handy for you : https://www.promisejs.org/

Comment: Although I'm a big fan of [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) for promises, you would have a lot easier time if you came up with a better way of organizing your callback code so what's going on is more obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Careful here! You're on the right track with realizing that this function is async and that you want to wait until every iteration of #eachpage has resolved before writing outputting your JSON, like a Promise would. But Airtable was kind enough to already provide what you're looking for: the callback

```
function done (error){
  if(error){ console.log(error);
    console.log(tab);
  }
}
```

will run immediately after the last successful call to #fetchNextPage. This is where you should have your JSON-writing logic. You would want something like

```
function done (error){
  TabToJson(tab);

  if(error){ console.log(error);
    console.log(tab);
  }
}
```

You don't need your function pushToArray, as you've already pushed the individual records from Airtable into your array 'tab' in each call to #page. Furthermore, if you want to do more than log your JSON output, which your question makes it seem, you should look into Node's [File System Library](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). checkout the fs#writeFile method.

Comment: I made my way with promises but +1 to your solution which also do the job! Now I wonder what way would be the smartest one to use.

Answer (score 3):

You can use async/await for it. Please make sure you can use await in an async function.

```
try {
  const records = await base('Table 1').select({ view }).all()

  records.map((record) => {
    tab.push({
        "Name": record.get('Name'),
        "Notes": record.get('Notes')
    });

    pushToArray(tab)
  })
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e)
}
```

Comment: `.all()` was my solution. Airtable is definitely lacking ease of getting through doc.